# Create cron job for update translations automatically

Tags: functions, translation, wp-cron, automatic-updates

I would like to set cron job in WordPress with [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) for update translations automatically. If I saw it right I have to create a PHP code (simple plugin) and then schedule it with mentioned plugin. How is it possible?

Comment: you don't need this plugin if you create your own. read this : https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [wp cli](https://wp-cli.org/) based solution. These below commands are useful for update translate files for core, themes and plugins:

```
wp language core update
wp language theme update --all
wp language plugin update --all
```

To schedule these commands, insert this line in crontab:

```
30 0 * * * wp language core update ; wp language theme update --all ; wp language plugin update --all
```

It will update all translate files once a day.

Shorter version of cron job:

```
30 0 * * * for i in "core update" "theme update --all" "plugin update --all"; do sudo wp  language $i; done
```